# How to launch an application after a specific Disc was mounted using Automator

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

I'm new to [Automator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automator_(software)).
There are many [examples](https://www.raywenderlich.com/58986/automator-for-mac-tutorial-and-examples) for simple actions.
But I couldn't find examples or [documentation](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT2488) for launching some applications after a specific disk was mounted.
It will be very useful at work.
Has someone done this?

Comment: Not Automator but Folder Actions: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3078916?tstart=0 or maybe have a look at launchd: https://discussions.apple.com/message/7949701#7949701

Comment: The last link is out of date (2008 year). The first one is interesting: `if class of thisThing is disk and name of thisThing is "MobileVAULT" then`, but complicated. I thing there should be solution without any script.

Comment: Ask on https://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: @trojanfoe i will, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, you want the Automator way, you get it :-D

1. Create a new Automator action of type **Folder Action**
2. Choose the **Volumes** folder of your System as input, I think you'll have to use `Go to folder` and type `/Volumes`
3. As first action choose **Execute Applescript**
4. Use the following script and define the first two variables to match your needs:

   ```
   on run {input, parameters}

       -- define the volume name and the application to start
       set triggeringVolumeName to "YOUR_VOLUME_NAME"
       set applicationToStart to application "Microsoft Word"

       -- walk through all newly mounted volumes
       repeat with aMountedVolumeAlias in input

           -- get the volume name from the given alias
           tell application "System Events" to set mountedVolumeName to name of aMountedVolumeAlias

           -- compare the volume name with the defined trigger name
           if mountedVolumeName is triggeringVolumeName then

               -- launch the target application
               launch applicationToStart

               -- all is done stop checking
               exit repeat

           end if

       end repeat
       return input
   end run
   ```

The trick is to watch for changes inside the default mount point of your system (`/Volumes`). Everytime something is added to the folder, the AppleScript will be executed and aliases of the newly added items (aka the new volumes) will be inside the `input` parameter given to the script.
We walk through the list of all item aliases and get the real name of the alias, compare it with our trigger name and in case of a match we start the application.

Have fun with Automator, Michael / Hamburg

Comment: Unfortunately when the mounted disk was specified inside `/etc/fstab` (`vifs`) the *FolderAction* won't trigger, because one needs to specify an existing folder as mount-point. Hence, Automator will not see any Folder change (no mountpoint created or removed).

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on ShooTerKo's answer I've written the following script that continues the Workflow if the triggeringVolumeName is found. That way the actual launch (or any other Workflow action) can be moved outside the Applescript:

1. Create a new Automator action of type **Folder Action**
2. Choose the **Volumes** folder of your system as input by clicking **Other...** in the **Choose folder** dropdown, pressing **Cmd+Shift+G** and typing `/Volumes`
3. As first action choose **Execute Applescript**
4. Use the following script and change `YOUR_VOLUME_NAME` to match your needs:

   ```
   on run {input, parameters}

       -- define the volume name and the application to start
       set triggeringVolumeName to "YOUR_VOLUME_NAME"

       -- walk through all newly mounted volumes
       repeat with aMountedVolumeAlias in input

           -- get the volume name from the given alias
           tell application "System Events" to set mountedVolumeName to name of aMountedVolumeAlias

           -- compare the volume name with the defined trigger name
           if mountedVolumeName is triggeringVolumeName then

               -- continue workflow
               return input

           end if

       end repeat

       -- if repeat finished without match, cancel workflow
       error number -128

   end run
   ```
5. Add other actions to the Workflow, e.g. **Ask for Confirmation**, **Copy Finder Items** or **Launch Application**